# How to return ctx in mangodb

Tags: node.js, koa

I'm trying Koa instead of express and I have a problem returning ctx.

Here is my code :

```
router.get("/user/:id", async (ctx, next) => {
  mongodb.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, (err, db) => {
    if (err)
      throw ("error => " + err);
    else {
      var dbo = db.db("test");
      dbo.collection("users")
      .find({})
      .toArray((err, res) => {
        if (err)
          throw ("error => " + err);
        db.close();
        console.log(res);
        ctx.body = {
          "message": "GOT IT"
        }
      })
    }
  });
});
```

The problem is that ctx is unknown in the callback.
Any idea on how I can put it into the callback?

btw res is filled properly.
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem with the callback has to do that you first have to wait for the

```
dbo.collection("users").find({})
```

And the do

```
toArray()
```

I use the koa-mongo library.
This library inject mongo into the context.
Open and close mongodb connection is not needed.

server.js

```
import Koa from 'koa'
import Mongo from 'koa-mongo'

const app = new Koa()
app.use(new Mongo(dbConfig))
```

In the router

```
 let db = ctx.mongo
 const result = await db.collection("users").find({})
 if (!result) {
      return []
 }
 return result.toArray()
```